# ¿Porqué la segunda llamada de la función registrar cita no se ejecuta bien?

Tags: c

La función registrarCita() añade un elemento de tipo Paciente a una cola circular. Todo marcha bien en la primera llamada pero cuando la llamo por segunda vez sucede esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo supongo que es porque la variable apuntador paciente sigue ocupada por ejecución de la primera llamada. Así que lo que hice fue liberar la memoria de la variable paciente y luego volver a reservarle un espacio, pero el resultado es el mismo. No hay ningún tipo de notificación en la compilación. En cuanto a la función capturaPaciente() ya me he serciorado de que no hay ningún problema con ella. Pienso que el problema podría estar en cómo libero la memoria de la variable paciente por lo que el problema también podría estar en la función liberaPaciente().

Las líneas de código donde sospecho que está el error tienen comentarios con asteriscos

```
#define MAXCHAR 40 //Máximo número de caracteres que puede haber en la variable nombre
#define MAXTEL 14 //Máximo número de caracteres que puede haber en la variable telefono
#define MAXCITAS 30 //Máximo número de citas que puede haber en la cola

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct DatosMedicos{
    
       float peso;
       float estatura;
       char *alergiaPaciente;
    }DatosMedicos;
    
    typedef struct Paciente{
    
        char *nombre;
        int edad;
        char *sexo;
        char *telefono;
        DatosMedicos datosmedicos;
    
    }Paciente;
    
    typedef struct cola{
    
        int inicio;
        int final;
        Paciente *citas;
        
    }queue; //cola circular de citas
    
    Paciente *creaPaciente(void); //reserva memoria para un apuntador de tipo paciente
    Paciente *capturaPaciente(Paciente*); //Pide al usuario que introduzca los datos del paciente
    void listarPaciente(Paciente );// Imprime el contenido de una variable apuntador de tipo  paciente
    queue *crearCola(void); //reserva memoria para la cola de citas
    void inicializarCola(queue *);// asigna el valor -1 a inicio y final
    int isEmpty(queue *cola); //Indica si la cola de citas está vacía
    int Elements(queue *cola);//Regresa el número de elementos que hay en la cola
    int isFull(queue *cola); //Indica si la cola de citas está llena
    void Del(queue *cola);//Borra una cita de la cola de citas
    void registrarCita(queue *, Paciente*); //Añade una cita a la cola de citas
    void liberaPaciente(Paciente *paciente);//libera la memoria asignada por creaPaciente()
    
    
    int main(){
    
        Paciente *paciente = creaPaciente();
    
        queue *cola;
    
        cola = crearCola();
        inicializarCola(cola);
        
        registrarCita(cola, paciente); //primera llamada
        liberaPaciente(paciente); //libero la memoria ocupada por paciente
        paciente = creaPaciente(); //vuelvo a crear el espacio
        registrarCita(cola, paciente); // segunda llamada ****AQUÍ ESTÁ EL ERROR****
    
    
        cola = NULL;
        liberaPaciente(paciente);
    
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    Paciente *creaPaciente(){
    
        Paciente *paciente = (Paciente*)malloc(sizeof(Paciente));
        paciente->nombre = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));
        paciente->telefono = (char*)malloc(MAXTEL*sizeof(char));
        paciente->sexo = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));
        paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));
    
        return paciente;
    }
        
    Paciente *capturaPaciente(Paciente *paciente){
    
        int aux;
    
        printf("Nombre del paciente:");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->nombre);
        printf("Sexo:");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->sexo);
        printf("Teléfono:");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->telefono);
        printf("Edad:");
        scanf("%i", &paciente->edad);
        printf("Peso:");
        scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.peso);
        printf("estatura:");
        scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.estatura);
    
        aux = rand()%6; // En esta parte asigno aleatoriamente un alergia. No tiene importancia
    
        if(aux ==1)
            paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = (char*){"antibiótico"};
        else if(aux ==2)
            paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = (char*){"polvo"};
        else if(aux ==3)
            paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = (char*){"cítricos"};
        else if(aux ==4)
            paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = (char*){"mariscos"};
        else if(aux ==5)
            paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = (char*){"chocolate"};
        else if(aux ==6)
            paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = (char*){"semillas"};
    
    
        return paciente;
    
    }
    
    void listarPaciente(Paciente paciente){
    
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", paciente.nombre);
        printf("Edad: %d\n", paciente.edad);
        printf("Sexo: %s\n", paciente.sexo);
        printf("Teléfono: %s\n", paciente.telefono);
        printf("Peso: %f\n", paciente.datosmedicos.peso);
        printf("Estatura: %f\n", paciente.datosmedicos.estatura);
        printf("Aléŕgico a:%s\n", paciente.datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente);
    }
    
    void registrarCita(queue *cola, Paciente *paciente){
        
        if(!isFull(cola)){
            if(isEmpty(cola)){
                cola->inicio = 0;
            }
    
            if(cola->final == MAXCITAS - 1){
                cola->final = 0;
            }else{
                cola->final++;
             }
                cola->citas = capturaPaciente(paciente);
                printf("Inicio actual %d\n", cola->inicio);
                printf("ADD: %s en final %d\n\n", cola->citas[cola->final].nombre, cola->final); 
                printf("ADD: %d en final %d\n\n", cola->citas[cola->final].edad, cola->final); 
                printf("ADD: %s en final %d\n\n", cola->citas[cola->final].sexo, cola->final); 
                printf("ADD: %f en final %d\n\n", cola->citas[cola->final].datosmedicos.peso, cola->final); 
                printf("ADD: %f en final %d\n\n", cola->citas[cola->final].datosmedicos.estatura, cola->final); 
                printf("ADD: %s en final %d\n\n", cola->citas[cola->final].datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente, cola->final); 
    
        }else{
            printf("Está llena");
        }
    }
    
    void inicializarCola(queue *cola){
    
        cola->inicio = -1;
        cola->final = -1;
    }
    
    
    int Elements(queue *cola){
        if(isEmpty(cola))
            return 0;
            else{
                if(cola->inicio <=cola->final)
                return cola->final - cola->inicio + 1;
            else 
                return  MAXCITAS - cola->inicio + cola->final + 1;
            }
    }
    
    queue *crearCola(){
    
        queue *cola = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
        return cola;
    }
    
    
    int isEmpty(queue *cola){
    
        if(cola->final == -1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    
    
    int isFull(queue *cola){
    
        if(Elements(cola) == MAXCITAS)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    
    void liberaPaciente(Paciente *paciente){//******posible error*********
    
        paciente->nombre = NULL;
        paciente->telefono = NULL;
        paciente->sexo = NULL;
        paciente = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Creo que deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Hay mucho código ahí pero me parece que estás usando siempre el mismo paciente. Siempre tratas el mismo puntero una y otra vez cambiando los valores de la misma dirección de memoria (perdiendo el valor anterior en cada cambio). Tampoco estás manejando bien la memoria de `alergiaPaciente`. Reservas con `malloc` pero luego le asignas la dirección de memoria de una cadena constante, perdiendo la memoria reservada con `malloc`.

Comment: Creo que deberías meter los llamados a la función dentro de un bucle, no es la solución completa a tu problema pero te ayudaría con la legibilidad del código.